# Как задать вектор функций в Matlab?

Tags: функции, matlab, вектор

Требуется задать вектор, состоящий из функций, например:

```
g = @(x, y) x.^2 + y.^2;
f = @(x, y) x.^3 + y.^4;
```

Предполагается, что обращение к функции g можно осуществить через обращение к элементу вектора.
Что-бы можно было указать вектор функций в качестве параметра в какую-либо пользовательскую функцию. Как это записать в Matlab?

Answer (score 1):

```
F(1) = {@(x) x.^3-43}; 
F(2) = {@(x) x*exp(-x.^4)};
F(3) = {@(x) cos(x)};
f = F{1} % лежит первая функция
x = 1;
f(x)
```

Пример кода демонстрирующего вектор функций.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать не вектор, а массив ячеек `{@fun1, @fun2, ..., @funN}`.

```
funarray = {@(x) x.^3-43, @(x) x*exp(-x.^4), @(x) cos(x)};
funarray{1}(1);

ans = -42
```